# There is a problem when i create a new web form, Failed to load type'GestorDatosServimed.WebForm7'

Tags: c#, asp.net

i just want to create a new web form in VS and the syntaxs is correct but the problem persist
[Failed to load type'GestorDatosServimed.WebForm7'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikOAJ.png)
.NET Framework:4.0.30319; Version ASP.NET:4.8.9214.0
Server error in the '/' application.
Parser error
Description: Error parsing the resource required to service this request. Review the specific parser error details and modify the source code file accordingly.

Parser error message: failed to load type 'GestorDatosServimed.WebForm7'.

Source code error:

Line 1: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm7.aspx.cs" Inherits="GestorDatosServimed.WebForm7" %>>
Line 2:
Line 3: .

Source file: /WebForm7.aspx Line: 1

Version information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.9214.0

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)
I tried to duplicate another one that works and change the code but the problem persis...[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rd1qw.png)

Comment: Did you build the application? Need to see the complete error message as text, not an image.

Comment: Server error in the '/' application.
Parser error
Description: Error parsing the resource required to service this request. Review the specific parser error details and modify the source code file accordingly.

Parser error message: failed to load type 'GestorDatosServimed.WebForm7'.

Source code error:


Line 1: <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm7.aspx.cs" Inherits="GestorDatosServimed.WebForm7" %>>
Line 2:  
Line 3: <!DOCTYPE html>.
Source file: /WebForm7.aspx Line: 1

Comment: Does the application build ok? Is this error happening when running/debugging in Visual Studio or when you deploy the app to the server?

Answer (score 0):

How are you adding this form?

And is this a web forms application, or some other type of project here?

As a general rule, you MUST use Visual Studio to add the web form, not some manual process.

So, on the application project explorer, right click, and choose add->new

This:

[image]

Keep in mind that before you try to work on the project, you do want to ensure that the webform work flows are installed BEFORE you try to open and work on the project.

You don't mention what version of VS you are using here, but assuming vs2022, then you want to from the menu go tools->Get Tools and Features option.

Then ensure that you installed these additional workflows:

[image]

And of course before you add any new web forms, I would try building the application first, and if you can't build the application, then it is of little use to attempt to add new web forms.

Comment: Thank u, i solved the problem was an error when i built the application